# Class 'List<User>' has no instance getter 'lenght'. Receiver: Instance(length:5) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling: lenght

Tags: json, flutter

hello I'm getting this error

```
Class 'List<User>' has no instance getter 'lenght'.
Receiver: Instance(length:5) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: lenght
```

and I don't know where is the problem I can't see any problem in the code and the list the json file is fine and there is no problem withe it probly som thing withe the FutureBuilder

this is the json code

```
[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "name": "maen",
    "dep": "softwere",
    "pic": "https://shorturl.at/jqsIZ"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "name": "maen",
    "dep": "softwere",
    "pic": "https://shorturl.at/jqsIZ"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "name": "maen",
    "dep": "softwere",
    "pic": "https://shorturl.at/jqsIZ"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "name": "maen",
    "dep": "softwere",
    "pic": "https://shorturl.at/jqsIZ"
  },
  {
    "index": 4,
    "name": "maen",
    "dep": "softwere",
    "pic": "https://shorturl.at/jqsIZ"
  }
]
```

```
Future<List<User>> getData() async{
        var data = await http.get('http://maen.mis-web.com/generated.json');
    
        var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    
        List<User> users = [];
    
        for(var u in jsonData){
          User user = User(u["index"], u["name"], u["dep"], u["pic"]);
    
          users.add(user);
        }
    
        print(users.length);
    
        return users;
     }
    
    
    
     void initState(){
        getData();
        super.initState();
     }
    
     Widget futureList(){
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null){
              return ColorLoader2(
                color1: Colors.redAccent,
                color2: Colors.green,
                color3: Colors.amber,
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            snapshot.data[index].pic
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].dep),
                    );
                   },
               );
             }
           },
          );
     }
```

Comment: You misspelt `length` at `snapshot.data.lenght`

Comment: notice in your itemCount `snapshot.data.lenght`, write it correctly `length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght
```

Should be

```
 itemCount: snapshot.data.length
```